# Hide search bar on front page of woo commerce website until re-seller logs in

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a basic WordPress eCommerce site [www.rockitdistribution.com](http://www.rockitdistribution.com/) I'd like to hide the search functionality in the header on my website until the user logs in. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpFZ6.jpg) ultimately I just want the unregistered user to see what we hold as a wholesaler but not actually be able to browse product. When a user that we have allocated a user name and password logs in I just want them to be able to see our sites products and so on. So nothing more than an online catelogue if you know what I mean so they can call us to make orders and not do so online. I want all the things I have demarcated in red to be invisible to the general public and only login and logout as well as the search to be visible to logged in users? I hope I am making sense. Please be gentle I am new to this

Answer (score 1):

Try this!!

1) For Search Bar you can directly do this check in the `header.php` if user logged in show the search bar other wise hide it.

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
}
?>
```

2) If you wanted to show the products according to logged in customer or visitor you have to create custom template for which ever pages should meet your condition and follow the same pattern showed above (`is_user_logged_in`).

Comment: Use the function is_user_logged_in() in combination with what is specified at this site http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-the-search-feature-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. Paste it in you header.php of the theme.

```
<?php
   if(is_user_logged_in())
   {
?>
     <style type="text/css"> .search-label{ display:none !important; }</style>
<?php
   }
?>
```

Comment: A savvy user would be able to still use the search by unhiding it after viewing the source.  You are better off to prevent searching all together by redirecting non logged in users to a 404 page if they try searching.